# Как правильно реализовать непрерывный фоновый процесс в Go?

Tags: golang

У моего сервера кроме основной логики (обработка запросов), есть логика, которая подразумевает непрерывное обращение к стороннему сайту (берет оттуда некоторые данные и обновляет базу). База для всего сервера одна. Вот вопрос: куда поместить эту логику в отдельную горутину, которая будет жить вечно, или в отдельную программу? Как это правильно реализовать, буду благодарен за любую помощь: статью, совет.

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, если работа вашей фоновой обновлялки имеет смысл в отрыве от основного приложения, то делать это отдельной программой, если работа обновлялки бессмысленна без работы вашего приложения - горутина

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [github.com/chapsuk/worker](https://github.com/chapsuk/worker)
Использую его для пинговалок всяких и прочих фоновых процессов, параллельных основному потоку.

Вообще, стараюсь использовать [Helium](https://github.com/im-kulikov/helium), прекрасный пакет, в котором есть все, что нужно для написания сервисов, в том числе и воркеры.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. скажем, пример использования приведите. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]